# MySQL : How do I partition based on Month of date

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-5.6

I have a table having id as primary key and date column.

I want to partition the data.. I felt month would be the best option so that I have 12 partitions.. How do I achieve that !

I am using mysql 5.6 on AWS RDS.

```
alter table report.track_pdp_visit partition by hash(start_date);
```

It gives me following error:

> Field 'start_date' is of a not allowed type for this type of
>   partitioning

Comment: Use a [range](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-range.html). Anyway, why would you want to partition a date by hashing it? Typically what people want to do is put current month (quarter, year..i.e heavily updated) somewhere different to the others (fewer or even no updates). Hashing the dates means that this month's data will be scattered among the 12 partitions.

Comment: can u suggest me alter script for the same ..thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are many restrictions on `PARTITIONs`.  But also, there are many reasons why they don't provide any benefit.

What do you hope to gain?  `HASH` partitioning does not provide any performance benefit, unless you are doing "table scans" now.

Vérace's suggestion is a way that would pass the syntax issues, but, again, not likely to have performance benefit.

If you need to delete the old data, then `DROP PARTITION` is an excellent reason for `RANGE` partitioning.  But that is about the only reason.  [See my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) for further discussion and code for doing the `DROP` and `REORGANIZE`.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-range.html), below is an example that range partitions by `YEAR` - change as appropriate.

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html) is the part of the manual that explains how to alter tables and add partitions. You should be able to take it from here.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR(30),
    lname VARCHAR(30),
    hired DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01',
    separated DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
    job_code INT,
    store_id INT
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ( YEAR(separated) ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1991),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1996),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2001),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE);
```